# Creating CalDav Calendar Events

Tags: webdav, caldav

I have a Baikal CalDav Backend running on an Embedded Linux server.  I can successfully create a calendar with the MKCALENDAR call with the following body:

```
<C:mkcalendar xmlns:D='DAV:'xmlns:C='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav'>
    <D:set>
        <D:prop>
            <D:displayname>Test Calendar</D:displayname>
            <C:calendar-description>Calendar Description</C:calendar-description>
        </D:prop>
    </D:set>
</C:mkcalendar>
```

However I have been unable to find an example of how to add events to this calendar.

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
<C:mkcalendar xmlns:D='DAV:'xmlns:C='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav'>
    <D:set>
        <D:prop>
            <D:displayname>Test Calendar</D:displayname>
            <C:calendar-description>I Am Testing</C:calendar-description>
            <C:calendar-data>
              <![CDATA[
                  BEGIN:VCALENDAR
                  BEGIN:VEVENT
                  UID:test123
                  SUMMARY:Test Event
                  DTSTART=20140920T080000
                  DTEND=20140920T170000
                  END:VEVENT
                  END:VCALENDAR]]>
            </C:calendar-data>
        </D:prop>
    </D:set>
</C:mkcalendar>
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction in adding events to CalDav calendars using html calls.

Comment: This is a good link [**Building a CalDAV Client**](http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/)

Comment: Thanks - it looks like I have something working now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to turn David's comment a proper answer to this question: This is a good link: [Building a CalDAV client](http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/)

To create an event within a CalDAV calendar, you need to use the HTTP PUT operation. With the iCalendar of the new event as the request body.

Like:

```
PUT /home/meeting.ics HTTP/1.1
Host: ...
Content-Length: ...
Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:test123
SUMMARY:Test Event
DTSTART:20140920T080000Z
DTEND:20140920T170000Z
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: can you please answer this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66312856/caldav-yahoo-report-free-busy-query-resulting-in-500-server-error] (caldav 500 server error response)