# caldav yahoo: Report free-busy query resulting in 500 Server error

Tags: php, caldav

I am trying to get free-busy time from calendar, for that I am making Report request with "Free-busy-query" query. In the response I am getting 500 error. I just copied the code from documentation, but it is not returning any result.

client Request

```
REPORT /dav/piyush138/Calendar/piyushkumar/ HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
Host: caldav.calendar.yahoo.com:443
Depth: 1
Content-type: application/xml; charset="utf-8"
Content-Length: 216
User-Agent: DAViCalClient
Connection: close

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <C:free-busy-query xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
     <C:time-range start="20210222T000000Z"  end="20210222T240000Z"/>
   </C:free-busy-query>
```

Server response

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
WSHost: tardis013.cal.bf1.yahoo.com
Set-Cookie: rememberMe=deleteMe; Path=/; Max-Age=0; Expires=Sun, 21-Feb-2021 09:07:36 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Age: 2
Date: Mon, 22 Feb 2021 09:07:36 GMT
Server: ATS
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Connection: close
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000
Expect-CT: max-age=31536000, report-uri="http://csp.yahoo.com/beacon/csp?src=yahoocom-expect-ct-report-only"
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

Answer (score 0):

(This is not a proper answer - but I will eventually edit it if we can find a proper answer to this question.  I didn't even know Yahoo had CalDAV support, so I'm obviously not the best one to answer this, but I can come with some suggestions).

The 500-error should only be given if there is some error on the server side, from that perspective Yahoo should probably fix something on their side.  Anyway, quite often it's given either because the server fails to parse unexpected input from the client, or that the feature simply wasn't implemented.

Please try to change T2400 to T2359, or bump the date and use T0000.  It's a long shot, I doubt it will change anything, but worth checking out.

If I understand RFC4791 correctly, support for freebusy-requests is mandatory, but in practice it's not always supported.  My guess is that Yahoo didn't bother implementing support for it.

RFC6638 specifies a different way to send a freebusy-request, perhaps Yahoo supports that.  See section B.5 for example on how to send such a freebusy-request - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6638#appendix-B.5